# How to setup swift in Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, swift

I like to try swift in combination with Eclipse + Tifig. I tried several ways:

snap:

```
snap install swift
swift 4.0.3 from luis.nando (lf-araujo) installed
swift
/snap/swift/5/bin/swift: error while loading shared libraries: libatomic.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

seems at my 64 Bit system swift has a broken dependency.

```
uname -a
Linux lappi 4.18.0-11-generic #12-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 23 19:22:37 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

using apt-get fails as well:

```
sudo apt-get install swift
swift
bash: /snap/bin/swift: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-make
umake swift
```